# Uncaught TypeError: $$rAF.throttle is not a function error while injecting ngMock to module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

There is code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMock']);
```

While loading ngMock such error appears. 
***Uncaught TypeError: $$rAF.throttle is not a function***

Comment: I have used latest version.

Comment: Ok are you using angular material?

Comment: Yes, I use angular-material ver. 0.11.1

Comment: Have u included its mock as well?

Comment: Are you mean angular-material-mock?

Comment: Yes.. that has the throttle fn defined on raf. Use [this one](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/angular-material-mocks.js) and include module `ngMaterial-mock`.

Answer (score 3):

Issue seems to be coming from angular material [which decorates **`$$rAF`** service to add `throttle` function to it](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/core.js#L68). Including `angular.mocks` is not enough hence. You need to mock angular material decorators too. You can probably use [angular-material mock found here](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/angular-material-mocks.js). It has [mock for **`throttle`**](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/angular-material-mocks.js#L82). You would also need to list the module `ngMaterial-mock` as dependency while mocking. i.e

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngMock', 'ngMaterial-mock']);
```

Comment: some times modules don't load. DO you know why it happand.

Comment: @Maksim Which modules do not load? may be you are missing references or something or not in proper order? Can you replicate it in a codepen or something? This [one](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/dYjppG?editors=101) has jasmine set up.

Comment: I download files via bower and deploy through webpack. Angular-material-mocks file presents in bower components but doesn't load to index file after deploy. Do you know the reason?

Comment: after deploy? does it work when you run the tests from your local machine?

Comment: Here is an example in the material code.... https://github.com/angular/material/blob/c13feb76bd05d026a71fc8e7c4a556a1ebd56831/test/angular-material-spec.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script for the mock is below the angularjs in your index:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-mocks.js">
```